# JavaParser visit method arg parameter clarification

Tags: java, javaparser

Could someone give me clarification on the usage of the second argument `arg` of the `visit` method as shown in the following code from the [JavaParser documentation example page](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser) ?

I can't find any information on the internet.

```java
public class MethodPrinter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // creates an input stream for the file to be parsed
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.java");

        CompilationUnit cu;
        try {
            // parse the file
            cu = JavaParser.parse(in);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

        // visit and print the methods names
        new MethodVisitor().visit(cu, null);
    }

    /**
     * Simple visitor implementation for visiting MethodDeclaration nodes. 
     */
    private static class MethodVisitor extends VoidVisitorAdapter {

        @Override
        public void visit(MethodDeclaration n, Object arg) {
            // here you can access the attributes of the method.
            // this method will be called for all methods in this 
            // CompilationUnit, including inner class methods
            System.out.println(n.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is quite simple.

When you call `accept` method with your visitor, you can provide this additional argument, which will then be passed back to the `visit` methods of your visitor. This is a basically a way of passing some context object to the visitor allowing the visitor itself to stay stateless.

For instance, consider a case where you'd like to gather all the method names you see while visiting. You could provide a `Set<String>` as an argument and add method names to that set. I guess this is the rationale behind it. (I personally prefer stateful visitors instead).

By the way, you should normally call

```
cu.accept(new MethodVisitor(), null);
```

not the other way round.